# Should I still post a question that I just figured out?

Tags: discussion

This is my first post on meta, but I've been using Stack Overflow for a couple of years now. In my time here, sometimes I've found that I 'rubber duck' myself while writing a question. I'll often figure out the answer simply from trying to make a very thorough question with a minimal example.

I just spent the past hour writing a huge detailed question, complete with multiple screen snippets, links to research, other posts, solid grammar, and everything that I'd upvote in other posts. I've always just tossed these posts in the garbage in the past and moved on, but I'm now wondering if it's worth posting in case someone else has the same problem. I would immediately reply to my own question to say I figured it out, but I'm not sure if that's cool. What if someone else starts working on an answer before they see that I've replied to my own question? It'd be a waste of resources and someone's time and effort.

Another big thing that jumps out at me is that condoning this style of posting would likely result in reputation farming, maybe.

What should be done with questions that almost get asked (given they're high quality)?

Comment: If I remember correctly you can post an answer directly when asking a question. There should be a checkbox or something similar.

Comment: @ModusTollens that's correct - there is a checkbox, so you can write a question *and* answer at the same time and post them together. [More about self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was unaware that I could post an answer with the question simultaneously.

Comment: The top 1 self answer on the network is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely. and one of the most recent is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641564/what-are-the-differences-between-the-private-keyword-and-private-fields-in-types .

Comment: If you're unsure whether the topic is a good idea, and you're sure you've researched the site for duplicates, it is possible to ask on Meta. Don't present all the information, just the core question and whether anyone sees a problem with the topic being posted and self-answered.